# How do i replace values with numeric entry "0.0" and replace them with "1.0" in R?

Tags: r, replace

```
      Date     V1
2015-01-11    0.0
```

Now there are many vaules like these in my data frame. So i want all of them to be replaced by 1. I think creating another dataframe with all 0 values and then replacing them with 1 and merging again using left join will not place them back to their specific dates. Please help!

Answer (score 1):

I got the answer, Thanks!

```
df= df %>% mutate(V1 = replace(V1, V1 == '0', '1'))
```

Comment: I believe it's worth mentioning in the question that the numbers 0 and 1 are actually strings, therefore this is the solution that works.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a base R solution

```r
df[df==0] <- 1
```